# Validate google access_token: GaxiosError: invalid_token

Tags: angular, nestjs, google-oauth, access-token, google-api-nodejs-client

My goal is to implement **google login**. frontend is **Angular** and the backend is **nestjs**.

```
Angular Version: 14.2.5
Nestjs Version: 8.0.0
```

First of all, in my frontend I get the `access_token` from google and send it to my nestjs sever to validate it and obtain more info.
in my Angular frontend with the help of [**angularx-social-login package**](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login) I get user `access_token` as follows:

```
  constructor(
    private readonly _authService: SocialAuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._authService.authState.subscribe((user: any) => {
      this._authService.getAccessToken(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(token => {
           // here, send this token to server to validate it with HttpClient
      })
    });
  }
```

In my nestjs Server, I installed [**googleapis package**](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) to validate the token

```
import { google, Auth } from 'googleapis';

oauthClient: Auth.OAuth2Client;
constructor(private readonly _configService: ConfigService) {
    const { google: { clientId, clientSecret } } = _configService.get('login');
    this.oauthClient = new google.auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret);
}

// to vlidate token.
 async authenticate(token: string) {
    const tokenInfo= await this.oauthClient.getTokenInfo(token) // Here I get the following error.
    console.log(tokenInfo)
}
```

> GaxiosError: invalid_token response: {
> config: {
> method: 'POST',
> headers: [Object],
> url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo',
> paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],
> validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
> responseType: 'json'
> },
> data: { error: 'invalid_token', error_description: 'Invalid Value' },
> headers: {
> 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443";
> ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000;
> v="46,43"',
> 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
> connection: 'close',
> 'content-encoding': 'gzip',
> 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
> date: 'Fri, 07 Oct 2022 09:05:22 GMT',
> expires: 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT',
> pragma: 'no-cache',
> server: 'ESF',
> 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
> vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
> 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
> 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
> 'x-xss-protection': '0'
> },
> status: 400,
> statusText: 'Bad Request',
> request: { responseURL: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo' }   },   config: {
> method: 'POST',
> headers: {
> 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
> Authorization: 'Bearer undefined',
> 'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/8.5.2',
> 'x-goog-api-client': 'gl-node/16.14.0 auth/8.5.2',
> Accept: 'application/json'
> },
> url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo',
> paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],
> validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
> responseType: 'json'   },   code: '400' }

I used another way to validate token with the help of **axios** with post method and following url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token={access_token}
```

but this method as well doesn't work.

I searched a lot but did not find any solution.

Thanks in advance.

##### UPDATED

based on this article

https://wanago.io/2021/07/26/api-nestjs-google-authentication/

Comment: Whats wrong with just using the tokeninfo call?   You understand that the google api node.js client is used for Oauth2 or authorization.   This is not the same thing as signin authentication these two access tokens may not be interchangeable.

Comment: @DaImTo- I get error above ``GaxiosError: invalid_token ...``

Comment: in this article https://wanago.io/2021/07/26/api-nestjs-google-authentication/ they used this method to validate

Comment: invalid_token is a catch all error, it can mean a lot of things.   Your server not being in sync with NTP, the client id and client secret may not match the one that was used to create it.

Comment: In the error I see `Authorization: 'Bearer undefined',`. That would seem to be the problem. No bearer token is being passed.

Comment: @R. Richards- thanks for your answer, How can I set Authorization: 'Bearer xx' in this method ``oauthClient.getTokenInfo(token)`` I tried this ``oauthClient.getTokenInfo(`Bearer ${token}`)`` , doesn't work.

Comment: seeing as you are using a sign-in package here you tried passing the id token